# Error on android 4.2, button back

Tags: android, button, back

I have a problem with my app, but only with Android 4.2.
I explain the functionement : 
-the first activity is to enter Login and password and permit the connection
-when I'm connected I start the main menu of application.
-if you use back button, you don't come back to login activity, with a system.exit(0) you arrive on the home screen  of your smartphone.

However, it work on all version under 4.2 but with Android 4.2 this application is killing and restart on the login activity.

Have you an idea ?

Comment: without an error log, no we dont have an idea

Comment: are you trying to override the behavior of the back button? i.e. to not allow return to the Login activity?

Comment: Yes sorry I can't have a log now, but I think that the problem is system.exit(0), I should prefered a simple finish(); to close the app properly.

Comment: You should never need to use any `System` calls in an Android application. There are Android equivalents of everything in `System`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{ 

...

@Override
public void OnClick(View v){

switch(v.getId()){

case android.R.id.home:

// Do your thing here..

break;

case android.R.id.back:

// Or here, if you prefer

break;

}

}


}
```